# Both left join and right join in only one linq query?

Tags: linq, join

**> ex:**
*I have some sample data like this:*

```
 Inputs                                         Outputs

        ID   | iAmount                          ID   | oAmount                             
        1    |10                                1    |2   
        2    |20                                2    |5   
        3    |9                                 4    |6
```

***> I need result as: amount = iAmount - oAmount event they do not exists in both table***

```
**Results**
ID  | Amount(iAmount - oAmount)
1   |       8
2   |       15
3   |       9
4   |       6
```

How can I solve it and any solution to get result from Inputs and Output to get Results like that?